# Finding the correct parameters in excel DB

Tags: excel-formula

I have a sheet with about 20 countries and 100 measures. I'm creating an interactive summary sheet. Been trying IF, AND and VLOOKup but unsure of which is best.

when you change country selection the corresponding fact should change. Eg:

Country x **and** measure y, look up correct value in data sheet z

Which is the best formula?  Thank you!

Comment: Please be a bit more specific on what you want, and what you have tried so far, see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to give you an answer without better understanding your data.

For example, how is the data stored 'in data sheet z'?

If you have a table where Country X is in rows, with Measure Y in columns, and the value at the intersection of the 2, `INDEX/MATCH/MATCH` will be the best way to craft a solution.

Are you able to post a screenshot of the data, preferably with column headings, so that a more complete solution can be provided?

Comment: Can't post a screenshot but In sheet Z the countries are in columns and the measures in the rows.

Comment: Please try uploading in other blogs and submit the link for image.